# System freezes, after reboot it stops recognizing NVMe drive completely from BIOS

Tags: 20.04, ssd, nvme

have one kind of hard question here (at least for me).

I'm using the PC without any issues, and without warning, everything freezes. I may happen in an hour, or in three weeks, but it happens, and I have no clue why.

Nothing responds, no keyboard shortcut nor mouse input gets recorded. This happens in fresh and non fresh installs.

So I reset the PC with the button on the case, and when it turns back on, it doesn't recognize the NVMe SSD anymore. I'm talking about BIOS level. No disks outside of my SATA HDD. After a while, it gets recognized again. No clue how.

Some clarifications: I thought this may have been due to an issue with a motherboard, with the NVMe, or with the BIOS. So, I changed everything, and yesterday I installed Ubuntu Budgie, but the problem happened again today after an hour of usage.

I'll give all the info I can:

OS affected: Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 (last one I installed), Elementary OS, Ubuntu 20.04, 19.10. I'm dualbooting with Windows 10.

Original HW: Intel i9 9900K, Gigabyte Aorus Z390 Pro WiFi, 32GB 3200Mhz RAM Corsair Dominator Platinum, two 480GB NVMe adata Spectrix S40g SSD, one 4TB Seagate Barracuda HDD, EVGA RTX 2080.

New HW: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X, Asrock B550 Steel Legend, 32GB 3200Mhz RAM Corsair Dominator Platinum, one 960GB NVMe Kingston A2000 SSD, one 4TB Seagate Barracuda HDD, EVGA RTX 2080, TP-Link WiFi AX3000.

My usage: Steam, web browsing, VMWare for work with a Windows 10 guest.

This issue has DESTROYED one of my NVMe S40g SSD. It's not recognized by any PC anymore.

I'm totally lost here. I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the latest UEFI and SSD firmware installed?

Comment: Hello @oldfred, yes, both the SSD firmware and the UEFI are up to date (Kingston didn't report any updates available through the Windows app, and UEFI is on 1.20, which is the latest  version from the Asrock website)

Comment: This is more related to boot configuration, but may show something. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair